# Duration unit in SQL Server trace file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, trace

I have generated a trace file in SQL Server 2012, not really sure about the unit of duration, it is measured by millisecond?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As CPU is in milliseconds.From the beginning with SQL Server 2005, the server reports the duration of an event in `microseconds` (one millionth, or 10-6 of a second) and the amount of CPU time used by the event in milliseconds (one thousandth, or 10-3 of a second). Even in SQL Server 2000, the server reported both duration and CPU time in `milliseconds`. In SQL Server 2005 and later, the SQL Server Profiler graphical user interface displays the Duration column in milliseconds by default, but when a trace is saved to either a file or a database table, `the Duration column value is written in microseconds`.

For your further ref [Interpreting CPU Utilization for Performance Analysis](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/winserverperformance/2009/08/06/interpreting-cpu-utilization-for-performance-analysis/) and [Here](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/monitor-windows-server-performance-counters)

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server 2005 and later, duration is in microseconds when saved to a file or a table, and (by default) milliseconds on the GUI.

> The SQL Server Profiler graphical user interface displays the Duration column in milliseconds by default, but when a trace is saved to either a file or a database table, the Duration column value is written in microseconds.

[View and Analyze Traces with SQL Server Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175848.aspx)

The visualization in SQL Server Profiler can be changed in the General Options:

[image]